# SQL Server CDC(change data capture) is used just for table data change? Can I use it to track procedure or other types of objects change?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

SQL Server CDC(change data capture) is used just for table data change? Can I use it to track procedure or other types of objects change?

BTW, are there some companies using `CDC` in their production?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says it captures DATA change - and SP's are not data.

it is not meant to capture the database changes, but to be a fast mechanism for a data warehouse to see what ata has been added / changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database trigger to capture DDL changes on a database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx